# How to add custom CSS to a specific block in WordPress Editor?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I want to add custom CSS to a specific block in WordPress editor.

1. Which is the best method to do that?

a. should I download a plugin for that; or

b. Edit the block as html and add custom CSS using the 'style' tag
[(Example image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4nwR.png)

2. is it okay to use the "Edit the block as html and add custom CSS" method, and what are the drawbacks of it?

If you took the time to read and reply, I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sorry, but this question is off-topic here.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic specifically - `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.` Instead, please try to better describe your problem and what you have done so far to solve it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ Your post contains multiple questions, which is not suitable for this site. You are also using an image to show code which is also not good. Please visit SO Help Center section on 'Asking' including the article on How to Ask a Good Question >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask